# OAuth2 and OpenID Connect Uses Cases/ Examples

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, facebook-oauth, google-oauth

I'm looking for some example of application (Facebook, Google, Azur..) using OAuth2 and OpenID Connect.
and I want to know how they're implemnting each flow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a web site that has some links to examples plus some guidance.
It might help you get started.   ..tom

https://wiki.idesg.org/wiki/index.php?title=Compliant_Implementation_of_RP_on_ASP.NET#Implementation_on_ASP.NET_only